# Android запуск UI потока с помощью AndroidAnnotations

Tags: android, аннотации

Решил разобраться с такой технологией, как [AndroidAnnotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki).
В заявленном функционале имеются две такие [аннотации](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/WorkingWithThreads#background):
@Background - запускает внешний поток, данная вещь отработала корректно.
@UIThread - запускает поток в UI, данная вещь отказывается работать.
Попробовал использовать стандартный вариант решения через runOnUiThread() вместо @UIThred, он отработал отлично.

Ошибка при использовании @UIThread:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-3-thread-1
                                                                Process: evilroach.com.test, PID: 27529
                                                                android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Классы, в которых пробую использовать аннотации:

```
package evilroach.com.test.presenter;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.Network;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.UiThread;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.androidannotations.annotations.Background;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.EBean;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;

import evilroach.com.test.R;
import evilroach.com.test.activity.HomePage;
import evilroach.com.test.activity.NotificationView;
import evilroach.com.test.model.Person;
import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmConfiguration;
import io.realm.RealmResults;

@EBean
public class Connection {
    private HomePage homePage;

    public Connection(Context homePage) {
        this.homePage = (HomePage) homePage;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public void checkConnection() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) homePage.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        Network[] networks = connectivityManager.getAllNetworks();
        NetworkInfo info;

        if (networks.length == 0) {
            makeToast("No Networks");
        } else {
            for (Network network : networks) {
                info = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(network);

                if (info.getState().equals(NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)) {
                    makeToast("Connected.");
                    checkSiteAvailable("http://www.android.com/");
                } else {
                    makeToast("Not connected.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void notify(String title, String text) {
        int notificationId = 1;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) homePage.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(homePage.getApplicationContext()).
                setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setContentTitle(title).setContentText(text).setAutoCancel(true);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(homePage.getApplicationContext(), NotificationView.class);
        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(homePage.getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

    public void makeToast(String text) {
        Toast.makeText(homePage.getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void createPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = homePage.getPreferences(Context.MODE_APPEND);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("name", "Cat" + new Random().nextInt(100));
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void readPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = homePage.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String name = preferences.getString("name", "No name");
        homePage.writePreferences(name);
    }

    @Background
    public void checkSiteAvailable(String link) {
        final int TIMEOUT = 1000;
        String result = null;
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(link);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT);
            connection.connect();
            result = "Connected to: " + link;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            result = "Connecting failed.";
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }

        displayResultsOnUI(result);
    }

    /*public void displayResultsOnUI(final String results) {
        homePage.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                homePage.showInfo(results);
            }
        });
    }*/

    //Tried to use @UIThread
    public void displayResultsOnUI(String results) {
        homePage.showInfo(results);
    }

    public int countRealmObjects(){
        RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(homePage).build();
        Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);

        Person personMax = new Person("Max", "Sych", 30);
        Person personSlava = new Person("Slava", "Martynenko", 20);
        Person personLeha = new Person("Leha", "Samoilov", 40);

        realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.copyToRealm(personMax);
        realm.copyToRealm(personSlava);
        realm.copyToRealm(personLeha);
        realm.commitTransaction();

        RealmResults<Person> persons = realm.where(Person.class).lessThan("age", 35).findAll();
        return persons.size();
    }
}
```

и,

```
package evilroach.com.test.activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.UiThread;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.otto.Subscribe;

import org.androidannotations.annotations.Bean;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;
import evilroach.com.test.R;
import evilroach.com.test.model.Person;
import evilroach.com.test.presenter.Connection;
import evilroach.com.test.service.NewsMessage;
import evilroach.com.test.util.otto.BusProvider;
import evilroach.com.test.util.otto.ButtonEvent;
import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmConfiguration;
import io.realm.RealmResults;

@EActivity
public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Bean
    Connection connection;
    @Bind(R.id.news_block)
    TextView newsBlock;
    @Bind(R.id.buttonMessage)
    Button messageAlert;
    @Bind(R.id.buttonInternet)
    Button internetConnection;
    @Bind(R.id.buttonImage)
    Button animation;
    @Bind(R.id.buttonCamera)
    Button camera;
    @Bind(R.id.imageView)
    ImageView image;

    @OnClick(R.id.buttonMessage)
    public void showMaps() {
        newsBlock.append("\nClick.");
        connection.readPreferences();
        getGoogleMap();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.buttonInternet)
    public void checkInternetConnection() {
        connection.checkConnection();
        connection.createPreferences();
        getDaggerActivity();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.buttonImage)
    public void AnimateImage() {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade);
        image.startAnimation(animation);
        BusProvider.getInstance().post(new ButtonEvent("Otto!"));
        writeRealm();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.buttonCamera)
    public void takePhoto() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void anotherButtonPress(ButtonEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(this, event.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);
        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), NewsMessage.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        newsBlock.append("\nShow.");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        newsBlock.append("\nHide.");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), NewsMessage.class));
        connection.notify("By!", "Don`t forget about us.");
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        image.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }

    // Tried to use @UiThread
    public void showInfo(String info) {
        newsBlock.append("\n" + info);
    }


    public void writePreferences(String pref) {
        newsBlock.append("\n" + pref);
    }

    public void getGoogleMap() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void getDaggerActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DaggerOutputActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void writeRealm(){
        int count = connection.countRealmObjects();
        newsBlock.append("\nRealm objects: " + String.valueOf(count));
    }
}
```

Весь проект: [gitHub](https://github.com/VyacheslavMartynenko/Test).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что существовало несколько вариантов импорта, которые я не заметил.

```
import android.support.annotation.UiThread;
```

нужно заменить на:

```
import org.androidannotations.annotations.UiThread;
```